# OpenLayers panning not working on Windows Surface Tablet

Tags: openlayers, pan, surface

When I open the following URL in the IE of my Windows Surface tablet I can navigate in the map.

http://openlayers.org/two/

When I try to re-create the page in this fiddle it does not work.

http://jsfiddle.net/m5jr3za2/4/

`a div with minimal javascript`

Instead of navigating in the map the whole browser is moved

Please help me find what is different in the fiddle.

Thanks a lot,
Ropo

Answer (score 0):

Found it. It needs

-ms-touch-action: none;

jsfiddle.net/m5jr3za2/7/ is working jsfiddle.net/m5jr3za2/8/ is not